# Mysql query with ip address couldn't be insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, field, syntax-error

Not a really mysql expert =( , I need more pair of eyes to check my query,yes just a look,I know it might be easy for you all , But its spent my 4 hours without any result.Or suggest some good method of debug this kind of problem , Thanks in advance =)

Suspect dots of ip address caused the error

I am using `$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the ip address and store in a 16 digit length varchar with utf8 unicode ci

```
INSERT INTO topup 
customer_id, package_id, type, amount, slip, bank, method, description, 
approval_ip, admin_id, status) 
VALUES(1, 2, 1, 200000, example.png, CIMB, Bank In, 
Description will store your additional infomation... , 175.145.207.112, 1, 0)
```

This is the error message.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Description will store your additional infomation about this
>   request,175.145.207' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not just the IP is the problem, any text field is. You have to quote the values properly.

Format your `INSERT`-statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO topup (
    customer_id, package_id, type, amount, 
    slip, bank, method, description, 
    approval_ip, admin_id, status
) VALUES (
    '1', '2', '1', '200000',
    'example.png', 'CIMB', 'Bank In', 
    'Description will store your additional infomation...',
    '175.145.207.112','1','0');
```

Integer values don't need the quotes, but you're not doing it wrong if you use them with every value.

Answer (score 2):

You should add ip => **175.145.207.112** in quotes, like:

```
'175.145.207.112'
```

Answer (score 1):

run this query!!!.,

```
      INSERT INTO topup 
   (customer_id,package_id,type,amount,
slip,bank,method,description,approval_ip,admin_id,status)
VALUES(1,2,1,200000,'example.png','CIMB','Bank In',
'Description will store your additional infomation... ','175.145.207.112',1,0)
```

for **real integer** u no need to single or double quotes in Query,

for character u must use the single or double quotes in Query,